# Prevent infinite recursive variable scanning

Tags: java, recursion, reflection, stack-overflow

I wrote a method to return a string representation of all the static variables in a package. It recursively scans those object for more variables and so on. The problem is some swing objects contain references to their parents and that makes a `StackOverflowError`. My question is, how do I prevent this infinite recursion? I was thinking about making a list of already listed objects, but what would happen if I have two variables that reference the same thing? It would only list one of them, which I do not want.

If an infinite loop is detected, it should return something such as "Infinite Recursion" like this:

```
var1 = {
  var2 = {
    var1 = Infinite Recursion
  }
}
```

To run it, call `dumpVarables(true)`. The deep variable is a flag to tell it whether or not to leave the packages specified.

```
private static ArrayList<Class<?>> getClassesForPackage(Package pkg) {//This makes a list of all classes in a package
        String pkgname = pkg.getName();
        ArrayList<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        // Get a File object for the package
        File directory = null;
        String fullPath;
        String relPath = pkgname.replace('.', '/');
        // System.out.println("ClassDiscovery: Package: " + pkgname + " becomes Path:" + relPath);
        URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(relPath);
        // System.out.println("ClassDiscovery: Resource = " + resource);
        if (resource == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No resource for " + relPath); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        fullPath = resource.getFile();
        // System.out.println("ClassDiscovery: FullPath = " + resource);
        try {
            directory = new File(resource.toURI());
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(pkgname + " (" + resource + ") does not appear to be a valid URL / URI.  Strange, since we got it from the system...", e); //$NON-NLS-1$//$NON-NLS-2$
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            directory = null;
        }
        // System.out.println("ClassDiscovery: Directory = " + directory);
        if (directory != null && directory.exists()) {
            // Get the list of the files contained in the package
            String[] files = directory.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                // we are only interested in .class files
                if (files[i].endsWith(".class")) { //$NON-NLS-1$
                    // removes the .class extension
                    String className = pkgname + '.' + files[i].substring(0, files[i].length() - 6);
                    // System.out.println("ClassDiscovery: className = " + className);
                    try {
                        classes.add(Class.forName(className));
                    }
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("ClassNotFoundException loading " + className); //$NON-NLS-1$
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            try {
                String jarPath = fullPath.replaceFirst("[.]jar[!].*", ".jar").replaceFirst("file:", ""); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$ //$NON-NLS-4$
                JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jarPath);
                Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
                while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                    String entryName = entry.getName();
                    if (entryName.startsWith(relPath) && entryName.length() > relPath.length() + "/".length()) { //$NON-NLS-1$
                        // System.out.println("ClassDiscovery: JarEntry: " + entryName);
                        String className = entryName.replace('/', '.').replace('\\', '.').replace(".class", ""); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
                        // System.out.println("ClassDiscovery: className = " + className);
                        try {
                            classes.add(Class.forName(className));
                        }
                        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("ClassNotFoundException loading " + className); //$NON-NLS-1$
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(pkgname + " (" + directory + ") does not appear to be a valid package", e); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
            }
        }
        return classes;
    }

    private static String getSpacing(int level) {//Creates fancy spacing to allow you to read the output better
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            str += "  ";
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static String dumpVarables(boolean deep) {//This is what returns a string of all static varables, you can simply run System.out.println(dumpVarables(true)); to work this
        String str = ""; //$NON-NLS-1$
        //Get a list of all classes in the "derby" package
        for (Class clazz : getClassesForPackage(Package.getPackage("derby"))) { //$NON-NLS-1$
            Field[] declaredFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : declaredFields) {
                if (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    str += clazz.getName() + "." + field.getName();
                    try {
                        str += " = " + dumpVarables(field.get(null), 1, deep) + "\n";
                    }
                    catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    private static String dumpVarables(Object object, int level, boolean deep) {
        //If object is null, return null
        if (object == null) {
            return "null";
        }
        //If object is one of these types, return its string representation
        if (object instanceof String || object instanceof Byte || object instanceof Short || object instanceof Integer || object instanceof Long || object instanceof Float || object instanceof Double || object instanceof Boolean || object instanceof Character) {
            return object.toString();
        }
        // Test if the object is an array and list it if it is
        String result = "";
        if (object.getClass().isArray()) {
            result += "[";
            Object[] objArray = (Object[]) object;
            for (int i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
                result += dumpVarables(objArray[i], level, deep);
                if (i + 1 < objArray.length) {
                    result += ", ";
                }
            }
            result += "]";
            return result;
        }
        String pkg = object.getClass().getPackage().getName();
        // Test if the object is outside of our package
        if (!(pkg.equals("derby") || pkg.equals("utils"))) {
            //If we want to go deeper, we can go outside the derby and utils package
            if (!deep) {
                return object.toString();
            }
        }
        Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
        result += clazz.getName();
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        String fieldStuff = "";
        for (Field field : fields) {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            //Make sure the field is not a reference to it's self or it is static
            if (fieldName.equals("this$0") || Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) { //$NON-NLS-1$
                continue;
            }
            //Some fancy formatting
            fieldStuff += getSpacing(level);
            fieldStuff += fieldName;
            fieldStuff += " = "; //$NON-NLS-1$
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                fieldStuff += dumpVarables(field.get(object), level + 1, deep);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            fieldStuff += "\n"; //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        //Some fancy formatting
        if (fieldStuff.length() > 0) {
            result += " {\n"; //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        result += fieldStuff;
        if (fieldStuff.length() > 0) {
            result += getSpacing(level - 1);
            result += "}"; //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Seems not trivial at all. What if (unlikely, but this happens) A references B which references C which in turn references A, or any more complicated/obscure pattern, instead of just referencing parents ?

Comment: you better start using stringbuiler

Comment: You wanted to store those references you already scanned. You could additionally store the referencing class.

Comment: @X.L.Ant This is exactly what is happening, `JMenu` is referencing `JPopupMenu` which is referencing `JMenu` and so on. I not not want to just exclude these classes because this could happen for other cases too.

Comment: not sure that i get 'not wanting to list it twice'. whats the reason that you don't want to just record where you have visited and not visit it again?

Comment: @simbo1905 I want to list it twice, I do not want it to list it once. This makes it easier to read. I simply want to prevent the infinite recursion.

Comment: The problem is ill-defined: what do you want to *do* when one of these "loops" has been detected?

Comment: i agree with @ScottHunter i don't the requirement please add explanation of the sample output to the question.

Comment: @ScottHunter I would like it to return "Recursive Reference" or something in place of the variable's fields.

Comment: Construct a graph with classes as vertices and the references as edges. Now you can traverse the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to able to tell not just when a class has been revisited, but when it is part of the ancestry of the current class (thus forming a loop).

Put that way, the solution is simple: keep track of the current ancestry (for example, as a list of ancestor classes), adding to it as you recurse, and *removing* from it as you return.

Then, when you arrive at a class in the ancestry, report it as a Recursive Reference and move on.

Comment: Can you please give me some example code? I am having trouble understanding how to do what you are saying.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks!